# Java model update multiple views

Tags: java, android, algorithm, design-patterns, view

Say I have this class:

```
public class MyModel{

   private int id;
   private int value;

   public MyModel(int id, int value){

       this.id = id;
       this.value = value;

   }
}
```

And I have some views that use this model, say like a toggle button and a check box(0 for ON/CHECKED, 1 for OFF/UNCHECKED). My views are spread out the UI and they all have values based on models.
I use a publish/subscribe method to update a value from the UI, it updates in the database, it pushes the value to the subscribers, they update the UI based on the id and value then they store it in the database.

My problem is, when having a lot of views, in different parts of the app, it's hard to search the view to update it when it comes from a push notification.
And my question is, can I make the view dependent to it's model. I mean, I want to update the value in the database and so all the view's that represent those values would update.

Comment: you  can try passing the view in constructor of modal class to manage all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interface for that view and use that interface for all of your views.